# Count repeated null values in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$items = ['a', 'b', null, null];
```

I want count [nulls] in this array which is `2`.

**But:** **Without** replacing them before working with. Like this:

```
$items = array_replace($items,array_fill_keys(array_keys($items, null),''));

array_count_values($items);
```

**And: Without** removing them from the array and put them out of the total. Like this:

```
count($items) - count(array_filter($items));
```

I'm trying to know more better solutions.

Comment: What's wrong with the second approach? Don't want to `count()` twice?

Comment: Repeated null values or all null values? `[null, 1, null, null]` is that two or three?

Answer (score 4):

You could [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) on the null values and [`count`](http://php.net/count) once on the result:

```
count(array_filter($items, function ($item) { return $item === null; }))
```

or in PHP 7.4:

```
count(array_filter($items, fn($item) => $item === null));
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/TOHdP**

Answer (score 1):

Usually the best is to be explicit, so simply iterate over the input array and count:

```
<?php
$items = ['a', 'b', null, null]; 
array_walk($items, function($value) use (&$count) {
    if ($value === null)
      $count++;
});
var_dump($count);
```

The output obviously is:

```
int(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_count_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) method. you can use it like this:

**- Solution 1**

```
$items = ['a', 'b', null, null]; 

$counts = 0;
foreach(array_count_values($items) as $item => $counter){
    $counts += $counter;
}
echo count($items) - $counts;
```

PS: `array_count_values()` just count string and integers.

**- Solution 2**

Or you can use `array_filter` to create `null` values array and count it.

```
echo count(array_filter($items, function ($item) { 
    return $item === null; 
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for `array_filter`

```
$items = ['a', 'b', null, null]; 

echo(count(array_keys($items, null, true))); // Output: 2
```

> Note the third argument must be **true** if you only want `null` to be counted, as true means do strict comparison (===)